# Kubernetes - Increase meteor/node memory limit

Tags: node.js, meteor, kubernetes

I'm running a kubernetes cluster and one microservice is constantly crashing with exitCode 134. I already changed the resource memory limit to 6Gi

```
resources: {
 limits: {
  memory: "6Gi"
 }
}
```

but the pod never goes above 1.6/1.7Gi.

What may be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about Kubernetes memory limit. Default JavaScript Heap limit is 1.76GB when running in node (v8 engine).

The command-line in Deployment/Pod should be changed like `node --max-old-space-size=6144 index.js`.